# Error in pie(effectifs, col = rainbow()) : 'x' values must be positive

Tags: r

The code I am using is:

```
    barplot(effectifs,col = gray(seq(0.4,1.0,length=5)), 
    main="Répartition des touristes")
    pie(effectifs, col=rainbow())# Diagramme en secteurs
    barplot(effectifs,col = rainbow(7))
```

But I am presented with this error when executing it:

```
    Error in pie(effectifs, col = rainbow()) : 'x' values must be 
     positive.
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. It looks like that `pie` needs a vector of positive values. Apparently, your `effectifs` contains negative/NA values.

Comment: On third row, rainbow needs a value.